# PHP Variable not displaying image that uses bloginfo('template_directory')

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to store a hyperlinked image inside a variable, and then echo out that variable for my WordPress website. I find it more convenient to use bloginfo('template_directory') so that I can go back and forth between local and live server.

But bloginfo('template_directory') within a variable does not work, it displays nothing. But bloginfo('template_directory') will work in other areas of my website. What could be the problem?

**CODE A works. Notice 127.0.0.1 in the URL**

```
<?php
$var = '<a href="http://www.twitter.com">
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/social/twitter.png" />
    </a>';
echo $var;
?>
```

**CODE B displays nothing. Why is the below not working? Notice below I am using bloginfo('template_directory') instead of 127.0.0.1**

```
<?php
$var = '<a href="http://www.twitter.com">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/social/twitter.png" />
    </a>';
echo $var;
?>
```

---

**EDIT**

**CODE C how to replace the word "twitter" with a variable? (I am referring to line 3 below, the word "twitter" that is located in img src)**

```
<?php
    $var = '<a href="http://www.website.com">
        <img src="' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/images/social/twitter.png" />
        </a>';
    echo $var;
?>
```

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use get_bloginfo for you want it in a var. Also no need for php tags when in a string.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

```
<?php
     $var = '<a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="'. get_bloginfo('template_directory') .'/images/social/twitter.png" /></a>';
     echo $var;
?>
```

Also also suggest using something like this instead for child themes. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri

```
<?php
    $var = '<img class="svg " src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/social/twitter.png">'
    echo $var;
?>
```

In response to your EDIT C code block, I'm guessing you are trying to loop through some social media icon links. This is how you might do that:

```
<?php
    // Array of social sites
    $sites = array(
        'twitter',
        'facebook',
        'instagram'
    );

    // Loop through each
    foreach($sites as $site){
        $var = '<img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/social/'. $site .'.png">';
        echo $var;
    }
?>
```

Comment: This works! Also, is it optional or mandatory to put the space before the period of `. get_bloginfo`

Comment: @leko It's optional you also could write this: `src="'.get_bloginfo("template_directory").'` The spaces are more for 
readability!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have PHP tags in PHP tags:

Just concatenate the strings:

```
<?php
    $var = '<a href="http://www.twitter.com">
        <img src="' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/images/social/twitter.png" />
        </a>';    //↑                                    ↑ See here
    echo $var;
?>
```

Comment: Rizier123 I cannot figure out, how can I replace "twitter" with a variable? I'm referring to the "twitter" in `img src` (for more info, see CODE C in my edit in post above)

Comment: @leko just write this: `. str_replace('twitter', 'google', '/images/social/twitter.png') . '" / ></a>';`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' )` and for that matter `get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' )` which is used for child themes. These was used in early Wordpress versions. In later versions these was "replaced" with more appropriate functions.

The correct functions to use is [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) for parent themes and [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) for child themes. I would suggest that you work through these pages carefully

As for your syntax, as explained in the other answer, you cannot use HTML and PHP in the same string without separating them. This is done using the [string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) which you can go and read up on in the link provided

It seems that you need to add social media icons. If so, check out these two posts. Specially read the one that @toscho done to my question. That should help you quite a lot with a few issues

- [listing repeating social media buttons](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98407/31545). Take your time on this one. This is an excellent post that helped me out big time when I just started out
- [Social share buttons using genericons](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139377/31545)

Comment: Thanks for the tips Pieter! Just to be clear, for stylesheet path, I should use this `<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>`
instead of `<?php get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>` 
--------------- Also, are BOTH bloginfo() and get_bloginfo() deprecated ? Am I allowed to use the following types of `bloginfo()` ? If not, what can I replace them with ?
`bloginfo('name'); bloginfo('description'); bloginfo('pingback_url'); bloginfo('html_type'); bloginfo('charset');`

Comment: Sorry, on the first statement, you are wrong. `get_stylesheet_uri()` should be used in stead of `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')`. This is used for the path of the main stylesheet, regardless of parent and child themes.

Comment: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` should be used instead of `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')`. This is the path to files inside a child theme. It does exactly the same as `get_template_directory_uri()`, except last is used for parent themes

Comment: `get_bloginfo()` and `bloginfo()` is not depreciated, but you have to be careful, some of it's values are. I will dig a bit deeper someday when I have time to have a look at the rest, but AFAIK there aren't any better alternatives.